# Sql 2008 Collation

Tags: sql-server, installation

What Collation should I choose for my Sql 2008 setup?

The setup is for an international company and Textual Data is Unicode. Default settings is based on Danish Locale PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To learn more about collations: [SQL Server Collation Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903(SQL.80).aspx)

In my multilingual apps I normally opt for: `Latin1_General_CI_AS`